# React Native PickerIOS font size

Tags: react-native

I am using PickerIOS in React native, but I went through the document as well as the source code, did not see where I can change the font size of the picker?

Thanks!

Comment: If you go into node_module -> react-native -> Libraries -> Picker -> PickerIOS.js you can either copy and make a custom version of PickerIOS or you can edit it globally from there (not sure how much customization can be done, but some can def be done there)